# Magento cookie settings for subdomain

Tags: magento-1.8, php, cookie

When I am installing Magento under a subdomain of my production domain, I cannot login to magento admin. For example, my domain name is example.com where I have installed magento and it is in production, I am ok with admin login.

However, I have a subdomain called test.example.com and I installed magento there for testing purpose. Now, if I try to login to the test site, I can't login. The username and passwords are correct. I see no error message. It just reloads the same login page. Same things happens when I try to login to my production site admin panel.

If I clear the cookies related to example.com and test.example.com and then try to login to the admin panel of example.com, I am fine. Now, when I try to login to test.example.com admin panel, the problem starts again. Below is the current configuration

[image: This is the current configuration]

Is there anybody who can help me solving this issue?

Comment: Try to change the Cookie domain for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved the problem by putting the cookie domain value to www.example.com to production and test.example.com to my test site from Session Cookie management from the admin. Although this solution will not allow users to login without www i.e. example.com/admin will not work. We will have to use www.example.com/admin for successfully login to magento admin

Comment: I would have loved an actual answer that does not rely on "www." being present for real life use :/

Comment: ... (continued) however I found out that's not possible due to cookie's domain inheritence per RFC 6265